# How to embed table from Google Sheets to Google Doc and preserve formulas & cell protection

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, embed

I'm created a Google Doc posted to the Canvas platform for individual students to record data from an experiment. (see below for screenshot)

In excel, I can easily

1. insert AVERAGE formula for each row of data
2. protect all cells except for those where students entered data.

I need to embed that same data entry table from Google Sheets in a Google Doc. However, when I  copy the selected table cells from the google sheet, neither the AVERAGE formulas not the cell protection copy over into the Google Sheet.

Neither "paste table with link" to Google Sheet nor "paste unlinked" produces the desired results of
(a) preserving the AVERAGE formula
(b) cell protection

I can do without cell protection, but must have the average formula working.

[[image: Data entry table Google Sheet to embed in Google Doc]

Comment: @serenesat Great edits! Is this an answerable question?

Comment: Those who have good knowledge on Google Sheet can answer better.